# Creating TableViewController using uiscrollview and uiview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How to create a tableViewController on our own using scrollview and viewcontroller. I actually tried by adding reusable views to scrollview and other such things. But i am stuck.

Please provide me links or ideas to do it as i am new to ios programming.

Comment: And why want to do that ? What is the issue in actual UITableView?

Comment: There isnt any issue with actual one.Just wanted to try it tat way.Can u help me out

Comment: Add your tried code and explanation so that we can extend it.

Comment: Sorry to say the classic line "Why reinvent the wheel?" but if there is no issue with UITableView , make your self a favor by using UITableView and save time? Also please post what you have done so far to help you out where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would approach it:

1. Create components and implement `UIScrollViewDelegate` in your `ViewController`
2. Calculate content size of your scrollView (sum of height of the subviews; sum of widths of your subview).
3. Create a method that determines what views should be added and removed on the scroll view based on it's content offset and frame (for example initially you may have content offset of 0.0 and a frame size of 50/100 so  only two suviews of 50/50 will fit in a vertical row)
4. Add your first visible views (in the visible part of the scroll view add subviews based " on what view goes where " )
5. use the `func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` to call the method you created at step 3
6. adjust and and refactor

Comment: Hey Andrei Durnea, i really liked your approach and am working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UIViewController` and add a `UITableView` to its view as a subview. Conform your ViewController to the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols and set it as the delegate and dataSource of the tableView. You can add `UITableViewCell` to your tableView.

Here is a step-by-step tutorial:
https://www.journaldev.com/14180/ios-custom-tableview-images-checkmarks

And please take a look at the documentation of `UITableViewDataSource` [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) and `UITableViewDelegate` [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate)

Comment: Thanks but this is not the answer to my question.

Comment: Ok sorry, I thought you only have problem with the UITableViewController not with UIViewController + UITableView. But anyway, I wouldn't create a tableView like scrollView since it does not support the cell reusable logic.